# How to override title for exposed filter views under cache?

Tags: 7, views

I want to override the title for Exposed Filter views.

I tried to use `hook_views_pre_view` `hook_views_pre_render` and `hook_views_post_render` and more. This doesn't help me because my views is under cache(if I clear cache then it works, but I have to do each and every time).

Is there any option to set title for cached views? I want searched field as page title.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any option to set title for cached views. I want searched field as page title.

Yes, you could use jQuery to grab the search field text and then change the title on page load. Probably, you will need to use cookies.